# How do I fetch data from my multiple websites databases and display it in main website?

Tags: php, json, database, laravel-5, architecture

Let's consider I have three separate websites for 3 different departments with different database, servers etc.

And also I have a main website where I want to get some data from all three websites and show it in main website.

E.g. In my main website if I want to get all users then it should query each of the 3 different websites, get the content and display it on my main website.

What approach should I use to achieve this ?

> I am not asking for the code and queries. I only want to know the approach.

Comment: "In my main database" Why are you using main database when all you're using is other 3 databases to query the result?

Comment: is data from other two websites needs log in to watch ?

Comment: Sorry, I want to only display it in my main website

Comment: @DrJManish yes you need to login to get data from other websites

Comment: then yes, you can do it..... With database from main website >> let user gets logged in >> At top of each page...check if user is loggedin >> then fetch data from other two websites to display on those pages.....

Comment: So, do you have database access to all of the three websites?

Comment: @AmitMerchant Yes all those websites are mine. I have complete access to website code, database and everything else. Problem is that I want to show 
 data from all 3 website into the main website.

Answer (score 1):

For this structure, It is best if you can make a centralized REST API which do the query.

For example, make api.yourdomain.com/query.php which receive your request (?mode=getusers&user=33) and return user data.

This way, you will know where to look for when you're about to do modification to SQL files. it will be less complicated and later on you can extend this REST API to support more queries or caching.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches

1. **Backend:** using cURL (cURL is a library that lets you make HTTP
   requests in PHP.).
2. **Frontend:**  using Ajax Call or Fetch requests (AJAX stands for
   Asynchronous JavaScript and XML.) once page loaded do ajax call to
   get data.

best approach would be to do at Backend side, using cURL calls.

for more about cURL vist here http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use even one sql to get all data from three servers but the better way is using webservice such as json or rest, because each website may change